# Аналог оператора spread

Tags: javascript

Читаю про ES-2015 на http://learn.javascript.ru, в частности использование spread.
Приведен такой пример:

```
'use strict';
let numbers = [2, 3, 15];
let max = Math.max(...numbers);
alert( max ); // 15
```

а ниже указано, что

```
Math.max(...numbers);
Math.max.apply(Math, numbers);
```

делают одно и то же.

Сам пример мне понятен, но что за конструкция приведена здесь:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, numbers);
```

???

Что за метод `apply`?

Comment: На том же  http://learn.javascript.ru есть статья https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply

Comment: ну что ж вы, в том же учебнике не можете найти? https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` позволяет вызывать функцию/метод в контексте другого объекта

```
const obj = {
  name: 'obj',
  method: function () {
    alert(this.name);
  }
}

obj.method(); // выведет obj
obj.method.apply({name: 'obj2'}); // выведет obj2
```

[Подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/call-apply#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-apply)

**P.S.** 
`apply` не совсем аналог `spread-оператору`. Просто `Math.max` принимает список параметров, в который разворачивается массив `spread-оператором`.

```
let numbers = [2, 3, 15];
let max = Math.max(...numbers);
// то же самое что и
Math.max(2, 3, 15);
```

`apply` же вторым параметром принимает массив, которые будет передан как аргументы в функцию

```
const fn = (a, b) => a + b
fn.apply(null, [1, 2]); // null потому что нам не нужен тут контекст
```

Comment: понятно, это типа рефлексии

Comment: @angry типо того, хотя для рефлексии есть отдельный объект https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect

Comment: __obj.method.apply({name: 'obj2'});__  откуда беретсья obj2???

Comment: @Избытоксусликов что значит откуда? мы первым параметром передаем объект, который станет контекстом для метода. Метод выводит св-во `name`, которое при вызове равно `obj2` (потому что передали такой объект )

Comment: @ThisMan << первым параметром передает объект,>> где там параметры ? `name: 'obj',`  может свойста обьекта вы называете параметром?Я просто хочу уточнить

Comment: @Избытоксусликов присмотритесь внимательно `obj.method.apply({name: 'obj2'})`, `apply(/** здесь контекст может быть просто объект {} */)`